# Dotted subdomain name or new domain?

Tags: dns, seo, subdomain, hostname

I have a company website hosted at www.BRAND.com (where BRAND is a generic name).

The company want to develop a "micro website" for one of their campaigns, named "Inspired By BRAND".

I have two directions:

- inspired.by.BRAND.com - which I personally don't like too much. I don't know why but I don't recall any web address similar to this one subdomain.subdomain.domain.com.
- inspired.BRAND.com - which I this is best suited for it. Fewer dots and similar to "more friendly" addresses subdomain.domain.com.

Any hints, guidelines, any thoughts is well appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, stackoverflow is for programming questions. Maybe your question is is more valid for webmasters.stackexchange.com or some other listed at http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Sorry, didn't knew about webmasters one. I'm a programmer myself and using stack as "the one". Do you think I should post this question at webmasters one too?

Comment: In my view if you read stackoverflow FAQ and "webmasters" FAQ you will see that your question is more suited for webmasters. I think you are free to post it there! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would probably go for `inspiredby.BRAND.com`. It reflects the name of your micro-site, sounds good to me, and is communicated easily by phone as it does not have any hyphens or underscores etc...

Comment: +1, subdomain sounds as better solution. Mostly because visitors know that it surely belongs to BRAND.com (not an phishing scam, some kind of fraud or anything else harmful)